# How to make a dictonary not have delete methods?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm working on a project and I have a dictionary in Python. Due to this being an "append-only" dictionary, I need a way to disable `.pop`, `.popitem`, `.clear`, etc. Is this possible in python?

I have tried:

```
mydict = dict()
#attempt 1:
mydict.pop = None
#Get error pop is read-only
#attempt 2:
del mydict.pop
#Get error pop is read-only
```

I have tried this on all delete methods with the same results.

Comment: Make a subclass of `dict()` and override all the methods that can be used to remove items.

Comment: Good idea, I'll try that. just do class newdict(dict): def pop(): pass I think.

Comment: And also `__del__`, which is used for `del mydict[x]`

Comment: and also `__delattr_`.

Comment: @Sayse: Read-only wouldn't allow *any* modifications, this question is not asking  how to do that.

Comment: @Barmar: You're thinking of `__delitem__`, not `__del__`.

Answer (score 4):

Using inheritance to *remove* functionality violates Liskov substitution (a hypothetical `dict` subclass would behave erroneously when treated as a `dict` instance). And besides, I can easily just `dict.clear(my_subclassed_dict_instance)`. The thing you're asking for is not, in Python terminology, a `dict` and shouldn't masquerade as a subclass of one.

What you're looking for is a fresh class entirely. You want a class that [contains a `dict`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), not one that *is* a `dict`.

```
import collections.abc.Mapping

class MyAppendOnlyContainer(Mapping):

  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self._impl = kwargs

  def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self._impl[key]

  def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    self._impl[key] = value

  def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self._impl)

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self._impl)

  # Plus whatever other functionality you need ...
```

Note that [`collections.abc.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping) requires `__getitem__`, `__iter__`, and `__len__` (which your use case faithfully implements) and gives you `get`, `__contains__`, and several other useful `dict`-like helper functions. What you have is not a `dict`. What you have is a `Mapping` with benefits.

Answer (score 2):

Subclass the `dict()` class:

```
class NewDict(dict):
    def clear(self):
        pass
    def pop(self, *args):   #Note: returns a NoneType
        pass
    def popitem(self, *args):
        pass
```

Now when you create your dict, create it using:

```
myDict = NewDict()
```

I quickly dumped this into the command line interpreter and it seems to work.

Comment: `dct=MyDict(); dct[0]=0; dct.pop(0)` raises an error (you need the other parameters)

Comment: 0x263A:  I've made the correction and thank you very much for pointing it out!